# html button is activating asp validation in html input form - Why?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to ask why after clicking on my custom button that just appends text to div that's inside form, then it activates asp validation of that form?

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="append_area">

    </div>

    <button id="appendChild" onclick="addText()">add new thing</button>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function addText()
{
  var div = document.getElementById('append_area');
  div.innerHTML += `test`;
}
</script>
```

Comment: By default a `<button>` is `type="submit"`. Add `type="button"` to it.

Answer (score 3):

Set your button type as button

```
<button type="button" id="appendChild" onclick="addText()">add new thing</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [described in W3C documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp), default `type` of the `<button>` element can vary across different browsers, so it is a good practice to always specify it explicitly.

In this case, the default value is `submit`, so by clicking the button you are inadvertently causing the submit action and hence also validation to be performed as well.

To fix this, just specify the button `type` explicitly as `button`:

```
<button type="button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
<script>
function addText()
{
  var div = document.getElementById('append_area');
  div.innerHTML += `test`;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

then you can call in code `onclick="return addText()"`

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form to a CGI program that resides on the server, it is usually programmed to do its own check for errors. If it finds any it sends the page back to the reader who then has to re-enter some data, before submitting again. A JavaScript check is useful because it stops the form from being submitted if there is a problem, saving lots of time for your readers.

```
<button type="button" id="ChildForm" onclick="add()">add new </button>
```

The CGI script is still more reliable, as it always works regardless of whether JavaScript is enabled on the client-side or not; but having this extra safety barrier is a nice thing to have in place. It makes your page much more user-friendly and takes out the frustration of having to fill out the same form repeatedly. It's also very precise, as you can point out the exact field where there's a problem.